# Is there a simple way to create 8 or 16 bit grayscale videos using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, compression, grayscale

I have been reading for 3 days however still can't quite wrap my head around how to do the following. We have been asked to produce a simulation video from matplotlib to evaluate a programme that only accepts u8 or u16 grayscale videos. I have managed to produce the required animated scatterplot using the following code, however only know how to convert to grayscale using the second chunk of code in CV2 that results in a lot of compression.

I would get marked down for both the heavy compression and not doing it within the animation code, however I don't know of a way to do it during the animation code.

Animation code

```
pixelx = 250  # length of x for resulting movie in pixels
pixely = 250  # length of y for resulting movie in pixels
fig2d = plt.figure(figsize=(pixelx/72, pixely/72), dpi=72)
ax2d = fig2d.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax2d.set_axis_off()
scatter2d = ax2d.scatter([], [], s=(pixelx*particle.rad/Env.X)**2, marker='o', edgecolors='none', c='#000000', cmap='gray')
ax2d.set_aspect('auto')
ani2d = FuncAnimation(fig2d, update2d, frames=(duration * fps), init_func=initial2d, blit=False, interval=1000/fps,
                      repeat=True)
ani2d.save('x.avi', writer='ffmpeg', fps=fps, dpi=72)
```

RGB to grayscale code

```
import cv2
source = cv2.VideoCapture('x.avi')
frame_width = int(source.get(3))
frame_height = int(source.get(4))
size = (frame_width, frame_height)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('xG.avi',
                         cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 200, size, 0)
while True:

    ret, img = source.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    result.write(gray)

    cv2.imshow("frame", gray)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
source.release()
```

Any help would be greatly apprciated

Comment: Try `ani2d.save('x.avi', writer='ffmpeg', fps=fps, dpi=72, extra_args=['-pix_fmt', 'gray'])` and `ani2d.save('x.avi', writer='ffmpeg', fps=fps, dpi=72, extra_args=['-pix_fmt', 'gray16le'])` (not tested, but should work)

Comment: You have RGB values and you are trying to convert to grayscale with matplotlib?

Comment: @kesh thank you, they seem closer but not quite

Comment: @wwii yes, so currently I produce an RBG animation with matplotlib, that I then use CV2 to convert to grayscale, however there is apparently a way to do it with zero compression directly in MPL. Otherwise I may try to get half marks by trying to figure out lossless RGB to grayscale compression in CV2

Comment: To do lossless, try `extra_args=['-c:v','rawvideo','-pix_fmt', 'gray']` (if this is your remaining issue)

Comment: @kesh extra_args=['-c:v','rawvideo'] was all that was needed, thank you so much to both of you

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)